# Equivalent of d3 scale.bandwidth() for a linear scale's ticks?

Tags: d3.js, svg, scale, axis

In D3, you can return the width between two bands with `band.bandwidth()`.

Is there an equivalent to this for d3.scaleLinear() for your given domain, provided you've set the ticks on an axis?

So if your tickValues domain is `[-2,-1,0,1,2]`, `scaleLinear.tickWidth()` would provide you with the difference between `scaleLinear(0)` and `scaleLinear(1)` (or `scaleLinear(-2)` and `scaleLinear(-1)`), or whatever you've set the difference between the ticks to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you know, there is no such method. Also, the very concept of a bandwidth (which carries no information) for a linear scale makes little sense.

But the interesting think about your question is that it's not about the linear scale per se, it is about **the axis** generated using that scale (as you said *"...provided you've set the ticks on an axis"*).

In D3 the axis generated when we use a scale is quite unpredictable (that is, the number of ticks and their values), specially when using a time scale. Besides that, you can change the ticks using `axis.ticks()` or `axis.tickArguments()`. Because of this, using `scale.ticks()` to get the values of the ticks is not an accurate method.

That being said, you can use a function to which you pass the axis group itself (an SVG `<g>` element), like this one I just wrote:

```
function tickWidth(selection) {
    const ticks = selection.selectAll(".tick text")
        .nodes()
        .map(function(d) {
            return +d.textContent;
        });
    return scale(ticks[1]) - scale(ticks[0]);
}
```

What it does is basically getting all `<text>` elements inside the `.ticks` groups, converting them to numbers (they are strings) and returning the difference in the scale.

Here is a demo:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([50, 450])
  .domain([0, 100]);
const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);
const axisGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);

const bandwidth = tickWidth(axisGroup);

console.log("the bandwidth is: " + bandwidth + " pixels")

function tickWidth(selection) {
  const ticks = selection.selectAll(".tick text").nodes().map(function(d) {
    return +d.textContent;
  });
  return scale(ticks[1]) - scale(ticks[0]);
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, this approach takes into account methods like `axis.ticks()`, which modify the ticks:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([50, 450])
  .domain([0, 100]);
const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .ticks(5);
const axisGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);

const bandwidth = tickWidth(axisGroup);

console.log("the bandwidth is: " + bandwidth + " pixels")

function tickWidth(selection) {
  const ticks = selection.selectAll(".tick text").nodes().map(function(d) {
    return +d.textContent;
  });
  return scale(ticks[1]) - scale(ticks[0]);
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```